# Failed to resolve: com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.2.8

Tags: android

```
Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.shuhart:StepView:v1.2.8
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/1042561/Desktop/live/Tribal_Welfare_Offline_24/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: Did you Add `jcenter()` to repositories block in your `gradle` file https://github.com/shuhart/StepView/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added jcenter() to repositories block.

Or may be you are working in offline mode. Try disable offline work option in Settings.

Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Gradle --> uncheck Offline work and Sync your project

Comment: i have already added  jcenter() to repositories and  uncheck Offline work and Sync your project still its not working

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Same error  " Failed to resolve: com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.2.8 "

Comment: Why don't you try to add as a module?

Comment: Abhay, please tell me how to add as a module. I download it from https://github.com/shuhart/StepView